# Cannot show longblob in an image tag

Tags: php, database, pdo, blob

I have been struggling with this problem for many hours now. The page is supposed to display a list of images from a database stored as longblobs, but all it does is to show me the 'img' icon for each icon. Any suggestions to what I can do?

showImage.php

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT filetype, picture FROM postcards WHERE ID=". $_GET['ID'];

$rows=$conn->query($sql);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    header("Content-type: ". $row["filetype"]);
    echo $row["picture"];
}

$conn=null;

?>
```

listImage.php

```
<?php include_once('connection.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="uft-8">
        <title>List database content</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM postcards";
            $rows=$conn->query($sql);

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo '<p>Upload by person: '.$row["title"].'</p>';
                echo '<p><img src="showimage2.php?ID='.$row["ID"].'"></p>';
            }

            $conn=null;
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tellastory";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $e="";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    };
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest storing the image path in the database, not the image itself. Makes things much easier.

Comment: `listImage.php` is calling `showImage2.php`, but your code is documented to be for `showImage.php`. Assuming that's just a typo here, then I wonder how you expect show image to work. It's outputing *multiple* images (via the `foreach` loop), but the `<img>` tag expects only *one* image.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php